# insert into sql database with unknown number of columns

Tags: python, sql-insert, pyodbc

I have a dataset that I have written into a dataframe and created a database that match the columns from the dataset - This is done.

Lets call the database: `test`

I then want to use `insert into` the database using `pyodbc` where I use the following:

```
sql_insert = 'INSERT INTO dbo.['test']([date],[stockrate],[volume])'

for index, row in database1.iterrows():
    cursor.execute(sql_insert,row.date, row.stockrate, row.volume)
    connection.commit()
    cursor.close
```

Hence: The columns in `sql_insert` is created dynamically from the columns of the `dataframe` - This works because the sql statement is in text format.

I the want to make the last part dynamic as well so the `row.date`, `row.stockrate`, `row.volume` is stored in a somehow variable? list? loop?

This so I do not have to write the full `row.\*` multiple times with different columns.

How can this be done?

I have tried:

1. Creating the last part dynamical and then make it as a text as the first part (which I afterwards no why won't work).
2. Created a tuple and made a loop inside a list which I couldn't get to work.

Comment: check if [dataframe to_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) helps. Keep a note of `if_exists` argument.

Comment: Hi Kaneki21, Thanks - I think the lib sqlalchemy will do the work but the reason why I want it to work with pyodbc is because that I have read it performance much better.

Comment: @Basilico, Unless you have benchmarked the performance or otherwise are certain the pyodbc solution is significantly faster you should start with a solution that works. If, and only if, that proves to be too slow (and it probably won't) should you worry about doing it some other way.

Comment: Hi Kurtis, You got a point in making it work first and then consider performance afterwards. I will go with sqlalchemy and see how it performance.